# PySimpleGUI displaying a URL .JPG

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pysimplegui

I am using [PySimpleGui](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I want to have a local place holder image.jpg until the button is pressed to load in a URL based JPG.

From searching around, I see people saying to use the [PIL](https://python-pillow.org/) import, however it's a bit unclear currently to me, how to achieve this with my requirements.

I also am using [Cloudscraper](https://github.com/venomous/cloudscraper) as whenever I would make URL request I would get blocked with a 403 error.

Here is test code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI import Column, HorizontalSeparator, In, VSeperator
from io import BytesIO
import io
import os
import cloudscraper

url = "https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/users/avatars/000/149/439/large/fe2b0699a4a2db62eb2814d44c81a0cf.jpg"
scrapper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(browser={'browser': 'firefox','platform': 'windows','mobile': False}).get(url).content
im = Image.open(scrapper)

print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)


imgViewer = [
    [sg.Image(Image.open(""), key="-ArtistAvatarIMG-")],
    [sg.Button("Get Cover Image", key="Clicky")]
]

layout = [
    [ 
        sg.Column(imgViewer)
    ],
]

window = sg.Window("Testing", layout)

def main():
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "EXIT" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        if event == "Clicky":
            window['-ArtistAvatarIMG-'].Update(im)
    window.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cDir = os.getcwd()
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sg.Image` only supports PNG and GIF formats and since the image is jpg you have to convert it to png and for this you can use PIL:

```py
import io
import os

import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI import Column, HorizontalSeparator, In, VSeperator

from PIL import Image

import cloudscraper

url = "https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/users/avatars/000/149/439/large/fe2b0699a4a2db62eb2814d44c81a0cf.jpg"
jpg_data = (
    cloudscraper.create_scraper(
        browser={"browser": "firefox", "platform": "windows", "mobile": False}
    )
    .get(url)
    .content
)

pil_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(jpg_data))
png_bio = io.BytesIO()
pil_image.save(png_bio, format="PNG")
png_data = png_bio.getvalue()

imgViewer = [
    [sg.Image(data=png_data, key="-ArtistAvatarIMG-")],
    [sg.Button("Get Cover Image", key="Clicky")],
]
# ...
```

[image]